# Xcode 6 frame by frame animations

Tags: swift, xcode6, uiviewanimation

So I want to make an animated background in xcode6 using swift. In Photoshop Ive made 10 gradient circle images. The first image is barley visible (Transparent) and the Last image is 100% visible. So in xcode, I want to make a frame by frame animation that will animate the images from barley visible to 100% visible. But im not sure how to code this with swift. Any help would be great!

```
 @IBOutlet weak var animatedPicture: UIImageView!

animatedPicture.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [UIImage imagedNamed @"Fadein1.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed @"Fadein2.png"],
```

I'm thinking something like this. But in swift, Not Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add your images to `Images.xcassets` named like this:

[image]

2. Add a `UIImageView` to your `ViewController` through `StoryBoard`
3. Create an `IBOutlet` to the `UIImageView`
4. Import these in your `ViewController`

   ```
   import UIKit
   import Foundation
   ```
5. Create an empty `Array` for the images

   ```
   imageView.animationImages = [UIImage]()
   ```
6. Loop through the `Array` of `UIImage`s 
   ("999" should replaced with the amount of frames you are using. Also, your first frame must end with all zeros i.e. Frame000)

   ```
   for var index = 0; index < 999; index++ {
       var frameName = String(format: "Frame%03d", index) // Frame%03d means AssetName/AmountOfZeros/Increment
       imageView.animationImages?.append(UIImage(named: frameName)!)
   }
   ```
7. Set a duration and start the animation! (It will loop forever unless you add `imageView.animationRepeatCount`)

   ```
   imageView.animationDuration = 2 // Seconds
   imageView.startAnimating()
   ```

---

Check [this link](http://news.ui8.net/create-a-custom-animated-loading-indicator-with-swift/) if you are still having trouble

Comment: What's up answer I wrote 6 years ago?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is change the alpha, then just use the 100% visible image and `UIView.animateWithDuration()`

If more is going on with the images than just changing the alpha, then check out `UIImageView.animationImages()` and its related methods.